# Bootstrap Affix

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap's new affix option, but I can't quite get it right.

I have put together an example at http://jsfiddle.net/yPgUu/1/ and the relevant part is

```
<ul class="nav nav-list" data-spy="affix">
```

The left nav starts off at the correct position. However, as you scroll down, then there is a gap at the top of the nav. I'd like the nav to always be at the top of the current view, instead of being a gap.

I've also tried playing around with `data-offset-top="200"`, but that just seem to makes the menu bounce around.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using css margin property?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

OK, so this needs to be done in two parts.

http://jsfiddle.net/yPgUu/2/

First, assign `data-offset-top="50"` and then modify the `affix` property in css

```
.affix {
    top: 10px;
}​
```